# Unit-тестирование iOS приложения

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Как считать json-файл, который лежит в ресурсах тесткейсов ? Проблема в том, что не могу программно подобрать путь к ресурсу.

[image]

Comment: Похоже что Вам сначала нужно кодом добавить необходимый файл в бандл, а потом оттуда уже с ним работать. Так как папка проекта XCode и папка iOS проекта это разные места.

Comment: Кстати если Вы имитируете сетевые операции, то можно очень просто поднять node.js виртуальный сервер локально у Вас на машине который будет отдавать Вам эти JSON'ы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алексей, файл считать можно самым обычным образом за исключением того, что скорее всего Вам нужно использовать не `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, так как `main bundl`e в случае тестового таргета Вам скорее всего недоступен, а `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]` (ссылка), где self - это класс вашего тесткейса.

А потом самым обычным образом: `urlForResource...` или `pathForResource...`

Еще, конечно, убедитесь, что на этом файле стоит галочка вашего тестового-таргета.

Если вопрос не решится, уточняйте.